# Selecting distinct value from database then counting each value that matches the result

Tags: sqlite

I have a database of Theaters and Movies. Each Theater has a theaterID and each Movie has a theaterID to match it to its theater. I'm wanting to select a list of distinct genres from the database within a following theater and count the movies that are within the genre.

Basically formatted like this

```
Genre    | Count
----------------
Action   |    10
Comedy   |     5
Thriller |     7
```

So far I've tried this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GENRE, (
    select count(distinct movie) from movies where genre = GENRE
) genre_count
from movies where theaterID = 7 SORT BY GENRE ASC;
```

and it does get a list of all the genres at that theater but for the count column it returns a count of all movies at that theater instead of the movies that match that genre. Is there a way to match those values in the inner query or I've also heard `JOIN` might work but I'm not sure how within the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use `GROUP BY`. This is not tested, but you can try something like:

`SELECT Genre, COUNT(*) as CNT from movies WHERE theaterID = 7 GROUP BY genre ORDER BY CNT`

Answer (score 1):

I will use your code and just point why it does not give you the result you want:
you must alias the table `movies` so you can use its `GENRE` in the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.GENRE, (
    select count(distinct movie) from movies where genre = m.GENRE
) genre_count
from movies m 
where m.theaterID = 7 SORT BY m.GENRE ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried to alias earlier with the AS at the beginning with genre but that didn't seem to carry into the inner function.